# Hosting multiple Wcf services in windows service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have multiple WCF service to host in windows service.
I was wondering, is there a need to create multiple threads for ServiceHost ?
What do I need to consider when hosting these services ?
For example:
Does one client blocks another ?
If one client fails does it effects on other ?
If one client has been throttled, will it throttle the other two ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceHost creates its own listen thread for every instance so it's perfectly fine to have more than one in one host.

For instance we have a service with 4 hosts here.

```
private ServiceHost _msp;
private ServiceHost _ps;
private ServiceHost _tt;
private ServiceHost _tts;
```

Windows also has a service running called "Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service". This way the hosts can even share the same port when running over tcp.

Comment: Tnx, I just needed confirmation of it.